# How to trigger logout in identity provider SAML2 Web in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Currently I am using WSO2 IS 5.1.0. I add ADFS as identity server and I specify logout URL https://myadfsserver.domain.net/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0 in . When I trigger logout from service provider, I don't see any logout request is sent to ADFS server. Is there any configuration missing?

[ADFS-Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r6nr.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to https://omindu.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/setting-ad-fs-3-0-as-federated-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server/ , "Logout URL should be the same as SSO URL". So please try without the query params in the logout URL.

Comment: I have configured one instance of WSO2 as SP and another WSO2 instance as IDP.. When WSO2 SP instance receives logout from the actual SP (custom application), it doesn't send logout request to WSO2 IDP instance